# Multi threading in per Kafka consumer per partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I am exploring ways to design a crawler which is at Google scale and hence exploring possible solution using Kafka.

Recently I learned that Kafka partitions are limited to thousands in number and won't scale beyond that. and also It's a well-known fact to have a single thread per partition(with or without consumer group).

**My question is how do I build high-performance crawler with tens and thousands of parallel workers to crawl.**

1. one possible solution is to have hundreds of topics and thousands of partitions and consumers(in equal numbers).
2. or have a thread pool for per partition consumers, like below shown diagram

[image]
Is it possible to correct/propose a perfect design which works with Kafka?

Comment: The big issue with parallel processing within a partition is offset management. With Kafka individual records are not ack'd, we simply commit the offset of the last message processed. Managing the offsets can be tricky, unless you don't have reliability requirements and can afford to lose messages and/or get duplicates after a failure.

Comment: Upon failure, What if the thread manager adds the failed messages to another retry topic?

Comment: By "failure" I mean catastrophic server failure (e.g. lost power or JVM crash) so the thread manager won't be able to do anything; if a later offset has been committed you won't get redeliveries of unprocessed earlier messages.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `partitions are limited to thousands in number and won't scale beyond that` -> cf https://blogs.apache.org/kafka/entry/apache-kafka-supports-more-partitions

Comment: It's also unclear to me, if you are talking about the read or write path?